# Animate seaborn heatmap using pandas and matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have plotted a static heatmap using one column of a dataframe, which I have used to create a pivot table.

I now want to create an animated heatmap which reads each column of the original dataframe, pivots it and then updates the heatmap.

My original data frame is a bigger version of the below:

```
                       value                    
percentage_time         0.00      0.15      0.16
region                                          
Anterior Distal     0.111212  0.119385  0.116270
Anterior Proximal   0.150269  0.153613  0.168188
Lateral Distal      0.130440  0.137157  0.136494
Lateral Proximal    0.171977  0.182251  0.181090
Medial Distal       0.077468  0.082064  0.082553
Medial Proximal     0.194924  0.198803  0.199339
Posterior Distal    0.164124  0.171221  0.166328
Posterior Proximal  0.131310  0.145706  0.136094
```

An example of the pivot table I am using:

```
antpost   Anterior   Lateral  Posterior    Medial
distprox                                         
Proximal  0.150269  0.171977   0.131310  0.194924
Distal    0.111212  0.130440   0.164124  0.077468
```

This is the code I'm using, whilst I'm not getting errors, the pressure map but it does not update - it is the colour of all zero values.

```
column_total_number = len(region_pressure_data.columns)
row_total_number = len(region_pressure_data.index)
fig = plt.figure()

def init():
      sns.heatmap(np.zeros((2, 4)), vmin = 0, vmax = 1, square=True)

def animate():
    column_number = 0
    while column_number < column_total_number:
        region_pressure_data_one_time = region_pressure_data.iloc[:,column_number:column_number + 1]

        index_parts = np.array(region_pressure_data_one_time.index.str.split().values.tolist())

        region_pressure_data_one_time["antpost"] = index_parts[:,0]
        region_pressure_data_one_time["distprox"] = index_parts[:,1]

        pivot = region_pressure_data_one_time.pivot(index="distprox", columns = "antpost")
        rowTitles = ["Proximal", "Distal"]
        pivot = pivot.reindex([rowTitles])
        pivot.columns = pivot.columns.droplevel()
        pivot.columns = pivot.columns.droplevel()
        columnTitles = ["Anterior", "Lateral", "Posterior", "Medial"]
        pivot = pivot[columnTitles]

        plt.clf()
        sns.heatmap(pivot, vmin = 0, vmax = 1, annot=True)
        column_number += 1

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, frames=20, repeat = False)
```

Is there something that I am doing very wrong or is there a more straightforward way of achieving what I want? Thanks in advance for the help! :)

Comment: It does not make sense to put the animation into the while loop.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I have altered this and I have edited my code in the question based on your comment, but am still getting an error unfortunately :( Is there something I am missing to update the figure?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, to be more clear: You should *either* use a while loop, *or* an animation. Not both in the same code.

Comment: I guess that is because the animate cycles through the frames? How do I define what the frames are i.e. each column? I'm a little confused with that...

Comment: Via the `frames` argument. The `animate` function should take this as input.